# Getting the average price of products in a category

Tags: mysql, sql

My database looks like:

```
Table - Products
products_id 
products_price 

Table - Products_to_Categories
categories_id
products_id 

Table - Products_Descriptions
products_name

Table - Categories_Descriptions
categories_name
```

There's a bunch other columns but these are the ones I need.

I want to select all the above columns but I also want to end up with an average product price **for each category**

I know it's probably going to include the AVG() function but I've tried a bunch of different queries (I'm a bit of a learner) and I'm buggered if I can figure out something that works. Is it even possible to do this with just one query? I just can't get my head around it at the moment.

Any help would be most gratefully received. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a query that will do it for one category, and you can then change the category id for each category.

```
SELECT AVG(product_price) FROM Products WHERE products_id IN (SELECT products_id FROM Products_to_Categories WHERE categories_id = x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to use GROUP BY clause when using an aggregate function.

Here is an example straight from the manual using the AVG function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Your query will be a little more complex because you need to join your tables but the idea behind using group by is the same.

Here is some more info on GROUP BY if you are curious
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Joining the tables and then a group by on category_name and/or category_id. The links highlighted above by Jrod are great references:

```
SELECT AVG(p.product_price), c.category_name
FROM Products p
    INNER JOIN Products_to_Categories pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
    INNER JOIN Categories c on pc.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_name
```